# T-SQL for Updating Rows with same value in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table lets say called `FavoriteFruits` that has `NAME`, `FRUIT`, and `GUID` for columns. The table is already populated with names and fruits. So lets say:

```
NAME      FRUIT       GUID
John      Apple       NULL
John      Orange      NULL
John      Grapes      NULL
Peter     Canteloupe  NULL
Peter     Grapefruit  NULL
```

Ok, now I want to update the `GUID` column with a new `GUID` (using `NEWID()`), but I want to have the same `GUID` per distinct name. So I want all the `John Smiths` to have the same `GUID`, and I want both the `Peters` to have the same `GUID`, but that `GUID` different than the one used for the Johns. So now it would look something like this:

```
NAME      FRUIT       GUID
John      Apple       f6172268-78b7-4c2b-8cd7-7a5ca20f6a01
John      Orange      f6172268-78b7-4c2b-8cd7-7a5ca20f6a01
John      Grapes      f6172268-78b7-4c2b-8cd7-7a5ca20f6a01
Peter     Canteloupe  e3b1851c-1927-491a-803e-6b3bce9bf223
Peter     Grapefruit  e3b1851c-1927-491a-803e-6b3bce9bf223
```

Can I do that in an update statement without having to use a cursor? If so can you please give an example?

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** a CTE won't work because [it'll evaluate per row](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions). A table variable would work:

You should be able to use a table variable as a source from which to update the data. This is untested, but it'll look something like:

```
DECLARE @n TABLE (Name varchar(10), Guid uniqueidentifier);

INSERT @n
SELECT Name, newid() AS Guid
FROM FavoriteFruits
GROUP BY Name;

UPDATE f
    SET f.Guid = n.Guid
FROM @n n
    JOIN FavoriteFruits f ON f.Name = n.Name
```

So that populates a variable with a GUID per name, then joins it back to the original table and updates accordingly.

Comment: "CTE won't work because it'll evaluate per row" -- the same applies to other table expressions e.g. the `USING` clause in a `MERGE` statement. Using `MERGE` with a table variable in place of a table expression will work, of course.

Comment: Thanks for adding that link.  I had heard of the issue, but didn't realize that they'd decided to close this as 'won't fix'.  The semantics seem wrong to me (certainly not what I'd expect).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify comments re a table expression in the `USING` clause of a `MERGE` statement.

The following won't work because [it'll evaluate per row](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions):

```
MERGE INTO FavoriteFruits
   USING (
          SELECT NAME, NEWID() AS GUID
            FROM FavoriteFruits
           GROUP 
              BY NAME
         ) AS source
      ON source.NAME = FavoriteFruits.NAME
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET GUID = source.GUID;
```

But the following, using a table variable, will work:

```
DECLARE @n TABLE 
(
 NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO @n (NAME, GUID)
   SELECT NAME, NEWID() 
     FROM FavoriteFruits
    GROUP 
       BY NAME;

MERGE INTO FavoriteFruits
   USING @n AS source
      ON source.NAME = FavoriteFruits.NAME
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET GUID = source.GUID;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a single-statement solution too, which, however, has some limitations. The idea is to use `OPENQUERY()`, like this:

```
UPDATE FavoriteFruits
SET GUID = n.GUID
FROM (
  SELECT NAME, GUID
  FROM OPENQUERY(
    linkedserver,
    'SELECT NAME, NEWID() AS GUID FROM database.schema.FavoriteFruits GROUP BY NAME'
  )
) n
WHERE FavoriteFruits.NAME = n.NAME
```

This solution implies that you need to create a self-pointing linked server. Another specificity is that you can't use this method on table variables nor local temporary tables (global ones would do as well as 'normal' tables).